Grouping Citations in Bibliography by Title
I am writing a dissertation which makes several references to newspapers / periodicals with the same name, issued on multiple dates over the course of many years. I am trying to group these references together by the periodical name, such that bibliography entries for the same periodical are close together, and separate from other entries for other periodicals.
I have looked through the biblatex documentation extensively, and the only relevant pieces of information that I could find are the bibnamesep and bibitemsep length registers. These seem to do exactly what I need - bibitems for periodicals with the same title should be closer together than bibitems which are not. The only challenge here is that bibnamesep seems to use nameparts and a uniqueness template to group together works by an author's name (and not by title).
This is my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Specify font encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Specify encoding (for example, UTF-8)
\usepackage[dashed=false,sorting=nyt,style=verbose,labeldateparts=true,uniquelist=true,uniquename=true,singletitle=true]{biblatex}
% Preamble - Here you can load packages and define settings
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mwe.bib}
  @periodical{TheSun:20220101,
    title = {The Sun},
    date  = {2022-01-01}
  }
  @periodical{TheTimes:20220601,
  title = {The Sun},
    date  = {2022-06-01}
  }
  @periodical{TheTimes:20220901,
  title = {The Sun},
    date  = {2022-09-01}
  }

  @periodical{TheGuardian:20210217,
    title = {The Guardian},
    date  = {2021-02-17}
  }
  @periodical{TheGuardian:20210311,
    title = {The Guardian},
    date  = {2021-03-11}
  }
  @periodical{TheGuardian:20210410,
    title = {The Guardian},
    date  = {2021-04-10}
  }

  @periodical{TheAlmanac:202302,
    title = {The Almanac},
    date  = {2023-02}
  }
  @periodical{TheAlmanac:202303,
    title = {The Almanac},
    date  = {2023-03}
  }
  @periodical{TheAlmanac:202304,
    title = {The Almanac},
    date  = {2023-04}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{TitleYear}{
  \sort{
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{month}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{day}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\bibitemsep=1pt
\bibnamesep=30pt

\nocite{*}
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=TitleYear]
  \printbibliography
\end{refcontext}

\end{document}

It contains 9 @periodical entries - 3 for The Sun, 3 for The Guardian and 3 for The Almanac. It sorts the entries by the periodical's title using the Sorting Template, and sets the \bibitemsep and \bibnamesep to 1pt and 30pt respectively. This is the bit that I cannot get to work:

As you can see in the image above, the references all have 30pt between them, whereas I would like "The Almanac" bibitems to have 1pt, but 30pt separating "The Almanac" from the "The Guardian".

\bibnamesep only applies between entries with a different name as encoded in fullhash. If you want to change this to title, you can try to (locally) redefine relevant internal macro that sets the separator.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
  style=verbose,
  sorting=nyt,
  dashed=false,
  labeldateparts=true,
  uniquelist=true,uniquename=true,
  singletitle=true,
]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
\def\blx@namesep@title{%
  \ifnum\c@instcount>\@ne
    \blx@imc@iffieldequals{title}\blx@prevtitle
      {}
      {\addvspace{\bibnamesep}}%
  \fi
  \global\let\blx@prevtitle\abx@field@title}

\newcommand*{\NamesepByTitle}{\let\blx@namesep\blx@namesep@title}
\makeatother


\DeclareSortingTemplate{TitleYear}{
  \sort{
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{month}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{day}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@periodical{TheSun:20220101,
  title = {The Sun},
  date  = {2022-01-01}
}
@periodical{TheTimes:20220601,
title = {The Sun},
  date  = {2022-06-01}
}
@periodical{TheTimes:20220901,
title = {The Sun},
  date  = {2022-09-01}
}

@periodical{TheGuardian:20210217,
  title = {The Guardian},
  date  = {2021-02-17}
}
@periodical{TheGuardian:20210311,
  title = {The Guardian},
  date  = {2021-03-11}
}
@periodical{TheGuardian:20210410,
  title = {The Guardian},
  date  = {2021-04-10}
}

@periodical{TheAlmanac:202302,
  title = {The Almanac},
  date  = {2023-02}
}
@periodical{TheAlmanac:202303,
  title = {The Almanac},
  date  = {2023-03}
}
@periodical{TheAlmanac:202304,
  title = {The Almanac},
  date  = {2023-04}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\bibitemsep=1pt
\bibnamesep=30pt

\nocite{*}
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=TitleYear]
  \NamesepByTitle
  \printbibliography
\end{refcontext}

\end{document}



Works brilliantly, thank you! Just out of curiosity, is there some documentation which you referenced that helped you arrive at that function definition? I ran through the biblatex PDF again and could not find anything of the sort. I also looked at the biblatex.sty and biblatex.def files but got lost in its logic.

@justin.saliba These kind of definitions you have to trace in biblatex.sty and friends. There is no documentation for them, I'm afraid. (The documentation only documents the public interface and we are messing with internals here.)
